# Android LinearLayout fill-the-middle

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a vertical, set height (300px) LinearLayout (LL) with 3 nested LLs. 1 and 3rd are set with android:layout_height="wrap_content" and the middle one with android:layout_height="fill_parent". To my dismay, 3rd LL gets pushed out with 2nd one filling parent layout right to the bottom. How do I achieve desired effect since I want potentially resize the outside container with the middle portion expanding and contracting to accommodate the change

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Turned out (Thanks Mark Murphy [for the answer](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a08e42713ce94f43/e9e31d27e3e31845?lnk=gst&q=droidin#e9e31d27e3e31845)) that all I was looking for was to set middle row to

layout_height="0px" and layout_weight="1"

> If, after all the wrap_content and fixed-sized items are allocated for 
>   along an axis (horizontal or vertical), there is still room on that axis 
>   left over, LinearLayout then allocates the remaining space to those 
>   widgets with specified weights, in proportion to the weight.

Comment: layout_weight only for the 2nd LL is the key here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Not sure why layout_height="wrap_content" and layout_weight="1" also work the few Android devices that I have tested.