# Stretch and fill middle Layout Android

Tags: android, layout, autofill, stretch, autosize

I have a Main Relative Layout(height,width=fill parent) that has 3 layouts inside it:

```
1st: Frame Layout(width=fill_parent/height=wrap_content)
2nd: Linear Layout(width=fill_parent/height=wrap_content/layoutbelow 1st)
3rd: Relative Layout(height=wrap_content/width=fill parent/layout_alignParentBottom="true"/ layoutbelow 2nd)
```

I want the 3rd layout to be at the bottom of the screen and 1st at the top of the screen and 2nd to fill the space in between. How do I do this? I followed this link:[Android LinearLayout fill-the-middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215757/android-linearlayout-fill-the-middle) and tried setting layout_height="0px" and layout_weight="1" but it did not work. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

1st: Frame Layout(width=fill_parent/height=wrap_content)

2nd: Linear Layout(width=fill_parent/height=wrap_content/layoutbelow 1st/layoutabove 3rd)

3rd: Relative Layout(height=wrap_content/width=fill parent/layout_alignParentBottom="true")

For Example :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnButton1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnButton3"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That did not work I got an exception: 
08-05 12:48:36.197 E/AndroidRuntime( 2389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 12:48:36.197 E/AndroidRuntime( 2389): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Comment: Ohk wait i will give you an example

Comment: Give me a second to try that.

Comment: Yes I see that. And it magically works. Thanks a bunch. I had another Relative layout too on top of my existing Relative layout, I changed a few properties and applied your code and it works smooth. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

IIRC RelativeLayout doesn't support layout_weight.

So you need something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_wight="1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So I implemented your answer and it works. However, I already have other multiple linear layouts on the screen and setting this relative layout to linear pushes layout outside of the screen. I might have to re-think my layout structure, i.e. change other layouts. However, I still have a question as to how to achieve such a functionality when one absolutely has to use a relative layout. 
Thanks though. I appreciate your help.