# Fixing siblings to bottom with expandable edittext

Tags: android

- I have a relative layout that sits at the bottom of screen
- It has 3 elements horizontal

  - firstElement - fixed width
  - middleElement - width as fill_parent
  - last element - fixed width
- MiddleElement is edit text with maxLines = 5. It starts with fixed width and then expands as typed.

With the layout below, I use `center_vertical` for left/right and they adjust accordingly to center.

My goal is to keep left/right elements to bottom while the edit text expands. I could not make it work,

**Below is just one example of layout I tried.** I have tried `align_parentBottom, layout_gravity=bottom, gravity=bottom.`

I could not make it work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottomComponent"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="50dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/green_theme"
        android:id="@+id/firstElement"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/firstImage" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/middleElement"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7.5dp"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="35dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lastElement"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstElement"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lastElement"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textColor="@color/title_gray"
        android:background="@color/green_theme"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="@string/lastElement" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok this post solved my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215757/android-linearlayout-fill-the-middle

Answer (score 0):

Ok this post solved my issue [Android LinearLayout fill-the-middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215757/android-linearlayout-fill-the-middle)

What I did not know that for linearlayout layout_weight=1 will work as fill_parent in relative layout