# How can my RecyclerView leave space at the bottom for buttons

Tags: android

I need to add some buttons at the bottom of a RecyclerView but whatever i do it always takes up the whole space and the buttons wont show on screen.

I tried adding padding that's the same size as the height of the buttons but it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/accueil"
            app:tint="@color/orange" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/redressed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/bleu"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Generer horaire"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ajouter tache"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change the `<RecyclerView>`'s `layout_height` to `0dp`, and set its `layout_weight` to `1`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1215757.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much it worked!